# Yum Installation fails - "Could not resolve host: elgis.argeo.org; Unknown error"

Tags: software-collections

Receiving following error when attempting to install :

yum install centos-release-scl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
*nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
http://elgis.argeo.org/repos/6/elgis/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: elgis.argeo.org; Unknown error"
Trying other mirror.
597 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package centos-release-scl available.
Error: Nothing to do

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The repo / the link http://elgis.argeo.org/repos/6/elgis/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml is an invalid address.

→ https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS
"The ELGIS repository is not maintained any more, use EPEL."

But CentOS 6 had "End Of Life" November 30, 2020, so "EPEL for old versions" (( https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/ ))  must be used. Example CentOS 6.10 EPEL repo file x86_64 :

```
[epel-6.10.repo]
name=CentOS-6.10-EPEL
baseurl=https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/6/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```